# Validate date in Pydantic less than today with condate

Tags: python-3.x, date, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to use pydantic for a fastapi app to restrict the provided date to be less than today. From the [pydantic docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#arguments-to-condate) I see a nice function `condate`, which has a `lt` argument - that's exactly what I need.
My code is:

```
from datetime import date
from pydantic import BaseModel, condate

class RiskData(BaseModel):
    
    dob: condate(lt=date.today())
```

which provides the following error:

```
File "pydantic\main.py", line 342, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for OpenAPI
components -> schemas -> RiskData -> properties -> dob -> exclusiveMaximum
  value is not a valid float (type=type_error.float)
components -> schemas -> RiskData -> $ref
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

I know that I can use `pydantic.validator` to achive the functionality that I need, but maybe pydantic allows me to save a couple of lines.

Comment: Also be aware that defining `condate(lt=date.today())` would have evaluted `date.today()` _when the application started_. Meaning that validation would break as soon as the next day rolls over.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Use a validator as described in the answer below, then use `description` on the parameter to document it for openapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like generating OpenApi Schema by FastAPI does not support Type: condate.

You'd better change to this,

```
from datetime import date
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class RiskData(BaseModel):
    
    dob: date

    @validator("dob")
    def validate_dob(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        if v < date.today():
            raise ValueError("Your Error Message")
        return v
```